# jQuery - Function on Hide Modal Not Working After Ajax Success On First Run

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4

I have make an `Ajax Request` and want to hide the `modal` after *success*. The problem that I am facing are, the function inside the hide method is **not working on first call** but if I do it again, it is working. Below are the codes:

**HTML**

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">User Id</th>
            <th scope="col">Time In</th>
            <th scope="col">Status</th>
            <th scope="col">LAST ACTIVE</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>

<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Delete Session</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Delete Session <span></span>?</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="deleteSession">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('#deleteSession').click(function(event) {
    $.ajax({
        url: `/session/${userId}`,
        type: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },
        dataType: 'JSON',
            data: {
            userId: userId,
            _method: "DELETE"
          },
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            $('#myModal').modal('hide');
            $('.alert.alert-success > span').text('Success');
            userId = "";

            $('#myModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
              // Function does not run on first call 
              $(".alert.alert-success").show();
              getSessions();
            })
        })
        .fail(function() {
            console.log("error");
        })
});
```

What is the issue and how to fix it?

Comment: do you get any console errors?

Comment: I did not receive any errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
        .done(function(data) {
            // hide modal (before)
            $('#myModal').modal('hide');

            ...

            // register hide event listener (after)
            $('#myModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
                ...
            })
        })
```

You hiding modal and after that adding hide action listener. Listener starts working after declaration, so it handles hide action just from second time.

And after that, when done occurs, you adding every time new listener for hide event without deleting old one.

I recommend to move `$('#myModal').on('hide.bs.modal', ...});` outside `done` method (what means create listener only once, when page loaded).

- **EDIT1: working code sample**

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {

  // create event listener once when page loaded
  $('#myModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
     $(".alert.alert-success").show();
     getSessions();
  });

  $('#deleteSession').click(function(event) {
    $.ajax({
        url: `/session/${userId}`,
        type: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },
        dataType: 'JSON',
            data: {
            userId: userId,
            _method: "DELETE"
          },
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            $('#myModal').modal('hide');
            $('.alert.alert-success > span').text('Success');
            userId = "";

        })
        .fail(function() {
            console.log("error");
        })
  });
});
```

Jquery [on 'event'](https://api.jquery.com/on/) don't runs operations inside of it, but register operations that will be ran when 'event' occurs.

Comment: do u mean example like, I create a ```function hideModal(){...}```. then, inside the done method, I call ```hideModal()```

Answer (score 0):

You could try `success(function(data))`

```
        success(function(data) {
            $('#myModal').modal('hide');
            $('.alert.alert-success > span').text('Success');
            userId = "";

            $('#myModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
              // Function does not run on first call 
              $(".alert.alert-success").show();
              getSessions();
            })
        })
```

Or `complete(function())`

In the Oficial [jQuery Doc](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

> Callback Function Queues
>
> The beforeSend, error, dataFilter, success and complete options all
> accept callback functions that are invoked at the appropriate times.

I hope it works

Comment: the function is deprecated